# Connecting three tables with two subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a somewhat crazy query that requires information from 4 tables. They all connect on the GRANTS table, and the other 3 I need to run sums on. T1 is a table that gives me access to the sum of the product of two numbers from separate tables. T2 is a table that gives me access to the sum of one item from that table. I then need to do some basic math with all those values plus a value from the GRANTS table to give me a result.

Here is the query I have:

```
SELECT GRANTS.[Grant Program Number],
         ( GRANTS.[Grant Request]
           - IIF(T2.CRM is Null, 0, T2.CRM)
         )
       - ( IIF(T1.EDC Is Null,0,T1.EDC)
           + GRANTS.Overhead
         ) AS [Net Net Request]
FROM       ( SELECT RESOURCES.[Grant Program Number] AS GPN,
                    Sum( RESOURCES.[Hours Spent]
                           * EMPLOYEES.[Employee Rate]
                    ) AS EDC
             FROM EMPLOYEES
             INNER JOIN RESOURCES ON EMPLOYEES.[Employee Number] = RESOURCES.[Employee Number] 
             GROUP BY RESOURCES.[Grant Program Number]
           )  AS T1
RIGHT JOIN GRANTS ON T1.GPN = GRANTS.[Grant Program Number] 
LEFT JOIN  ( SELECT COLLABORATORS.[Grant Program Number] AS GPN,
             Sum(COLLABORATORS.[Request Made]) AS CRM
             FROM COLLABORATORS 
             GROUP BY COLLABORATORS.[Grant Program Number]
           ) AS T2 ON GRANTS.[Grant Program Number] = T2.GPN
WHERE GRANTS.[Grant Submitted] = Yes
  AND GRANTS.[Submission Date] >= Forms!StartDate!Text0
  AND GRANTS.[Submission Date] <= DateAdd("m",+12,Forms!StartDate!Text0)
;
```

If I remove T1 and the SELECT values referenced from T1 in the main SELECT, it works. Same goes if I remove T2 and keep T1. But when they are there together I get `Syntax error (missing operator)` over the large FROM statement connecting the 3 tables.

Thanks.

Comment: This is almost impossible to read, let alone debug/enhance, I would suggest thinking about using temp tables and joining the temp tables

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that when connecting 3 tables together, you must close the first connection in parenthesis. I roughly had:

```
Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2 LEFT JOIN Table3
```

where I needed

```
(Table1 RIGHT JOIN Table2) LEFT JOIN Table3
```